# Reshuffling deck of cards

Tags: java, arrays

for the code below I need to track a card after a series of multiple shuffles in one run. I have used a for loop, Ofindex(), and Object.equals to find the position of the card. I need help with the reshuffle of the deck after it compiles

how would I go about reshuffling the deck in the code so when I go to find the position of the card in the for loop. it finds a different position everytime

code below is what we are given to build off of. not my personal code

```
private static String[] createDeck()
      {

           String[] SUITS = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"};
           String[] RANKS = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace" };
 
           // Deck creation code
           String[] deck = new String[RANKS.length*SUITS.length];
           for (int i=0; i< RANKS.length; i++)
                 for (int j=0; j< SUITS.length; j++)
                       deck[SUITS.length*i+j] = RANKS[i] + " of " +SUITS[j];
 
 
           return deck;
      }
     
      private static String[] shuffleDeck(String[] deck)
      {
           //Shuffle Code
           int n = deck.length;
           for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
           {
                 int r = i + (int)(Math.random()*(n-i));
                 String temp = deck[i];
                 deck[i] = deck[r];
                 deck[r] = temp;
           }
           return deck;
      }
```

This would be the public static void main part

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int y = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
System.out.println("Shuffling " + x + " times.");
System.out.println(deck[y]);
System.out.println();
int Y = y-1;
System.out.println("Starting Position: "+ Y );

//Objects.equals("test", new String("test"))

for(int L = 0; L < x; L++) {
  
  for (int f = 0; f < deck.length; f++) {
    
    if (Objects.equals(deck[f], new String(deck[y]))) {
    
      System.out.println("Shuffle " + (L + 1) + ": " + f);
```

keep in mind that some of this will not work with the code above it, as ive said I took out the private static String so I would be able to use some of the upper code.

Comment: When you say position, do you mean physical position on the screen or position inside the array?

Comment: position inside the array deck. the output should be 0-51

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking, do you think you could go into more detail or give an example?

Comment: with the above code, what would be my best option to be able to reshuffle the deck of cards as I don't use the above code word for word because I couldn't figure out how to. I personally took out the private static string lines to be able to use the individual variables (for example calling deck[x] to produce a card "9 of hearts" outside of the private static String ) for a different part of the assignment

Comment: When do you want to reshuffle the deck? Every time left-click is pressed? When the spacebar is pressed? Every 5 seconds?

Comment: I basically just need help on how I am able to reshuffle the deck inside a for loop so the outputs of the position of the cards are different. outputs should be like shuffle 1: position 5 shuffle 2: position 42 and so on depending on the # of loops

Comment: @MorganS42 the shuffle should happen in a for loop. every time it restarts the loop the deck gets reshuffled

Comment: Okay I think I understand now; but just for a bit more context do you think you could post the whole file? Including the public static void main? Just by editing your question.

Comment: @MorganS42 ive added the extra code. if that made it more confusing you'll have to give me some time to format it to the original code.

Comment: the outcome of my code is as following. Shuffling 3 times.
9 of Diamonds

Starting Position: 0
Shuffle 1: 1
Shuffle 2: 1
Shuffle 3: 1

Answer (score 0):

your code have a probem in this line:

```
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    int r = i + (int)(Math.random()*(n-i));
```

variable `r` will be set a random number from `i` to `n`(include `i`),so The card may be exchanged with itself.

If you wish to change the position of all cards after shuffling, you should change the line of code to this:

```
for (int i=0; i<n-2; i++){
    int r = i + (int)(Math.random()*(n-i-1)+1);
```

Comment: I was questioning this line last night as well. however that line was derived from a book and online from our professor so if its not 100% perfect shuffle then Tis all good. but thank you for answering my question from last night :)